# How to make visible the fund sign on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use the pound sign but there is a question mark. Any idea how to show this?

Here is my code where I insert that sign

```
setInterval(function() {
            $('p').fadeOut(500, function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.text($this.text() == 'throw your family at it' ? 'now available from £12.995' : 'throw your family at it');        
                $this.toggleClass('first second');        
                $this.fadeIn(500);
            });
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: Can you add your code to fiddle?

Comment: This question should be tagged with `html` as it is clear asking for a special character in HTML. The tags for `javascript` and `jquery` can stay there since the code example is using this language/library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method of jQuery instead of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Something like:

```
$('p').html('now available from &pound;12.995');
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uczxkzw6/

And read more on Special Characters of HTML [here](http://character-code.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using incorrect or incongruence charsets in your js and html. Try with html entities. Here you are a complete refference:

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

```
  now available from &pound;12.995
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your html header.

> **For HTML4**

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

> **For HTML5**

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: The charset must to be the same in the IDE editor than the html code. If you write code in ISO-8859-1 and specify in html UTF-8 is incorrect.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It is just an example to use meta tag.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remove the downvote, but if the user don't know how charset works it can be a confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

@Markus you can use this `code`

```
    setInterval(function() {
        $('p').fadeOut(500, function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.text($this.text() == 'throw your family at it' ? 'now available from &#163;12.995' : 'throw your family at it');        
            $this.toggleClass('first second');        
            $this.fadeIn(500);
        });
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Now it is going to show me that code `&#163;` and I am using `<meta charset="UTF-8">`